# Problems connecting to remote MySQL host with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I wanted to connect to a remote MySQL host (with `rake db:create`), but Rails always considers it to be local.
Database.yml which uses the following config:

```
defaults: &defaults
  encoding: unicode
  adapter: mysql
  username: <username>
  password: *************
  port: 3306
  host: <remote ip address>

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: <db name>
test: &test
  <<: *defaults
  database: <db name>
production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: <db name>
```

And always get this error when trying anything on the database:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The config works as long as I use the local database (i.e. without the host/port part).
Connecting to the remote MySQL server works fine with the given details.

Any ideas on what is going wrong ?

**Edit**:
The problem only occurs with `rake:db:create`, other tasks work - The error message was really badly misleading.

Comment: can you paste the complete database.yml ? and which env you use ? I suppose you define a socket configuration somewhere.

Comment: (see edit, seems to be a strange wrong error message)

Comment: Check your firewall/router settings, it doesn't seem you are having a TCP connection at all or the port is blocked.

Comment: It's resolved - just the create rake task didnt work. Everything else is working. No idea why rails assumes that create is local.

Comment: does the create task connect using different user than others ? If so, check the mysql table, and maybe the host column need to be changed, also `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` might help, by default mysql assume connect via socket, which you need to explicitly telling using port in remote access

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable MySQL server to accept remote request (by binding to host's ip address or all address format `0.0.0.0`). Edit MySQL configuration file `my.cnf` on the remote host. In Ubuntu, you can find the file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Change the value of bind-address:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Or just comment out bind-address.

Comment: You have to write this. commenting out won't work since that will consider accepting connecting only from current host.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing.  I was using this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

And it was complaining about not being able to find `/tmp/mysql.sock` (which is only in the development section of `database.yml`).  If I checked `Rails.env` from the console it correctly said production.  The fix is as simple as:

```
RACK_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```