# cannot connect rails app to remote mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am having trouble connecting my rails 2.3.5 app to a remote database.

In my database.yml I have:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: master
  username: user
  password: password
  host: 192.168.1.113
```

The error I get is:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

i know that the problem is not in the permissions or user set up because when I run a simple ruby script with the same mysql gem it works. Also my python scripts can connect and I can connect via CLI with `mysql -u user -ppass -h 192.168.1.113`

I just cannot seem to get rails to use 192.168.1.113 instead of localhost.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: in the cli you are using password as pass and in database.yml you have put it as "password"

Comment: right, typo on my part. the cli connection works, it's the rails connection that will not, thanks

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration and let me know if it works

```
<% socket_locations = %w[/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock] %>

development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: master
  username: user
  password: password
  host: 192.168.1.113
  socket: <%= socket_locations.detect { |f| File.exists?(f) } %>
```

Comment: can you try it in a different envt other than development. Create your  own custom envt like localdemo or something like that.here's another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195255/problems-connecting-to-remote-mysql-host-with-rails

Comment: sorry, don't really know how to create a custom environment and connect to it. At least, i did not understand how it was done in the example or link... thanks

Comment: link was great, but got the same results..  https://gist.github.com/3914690 thanks

Comment: Another simple way to test this is switching to the script/console mode and using the ActiveRecord.establish_connection method . Docs here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class . This will help you identify if there are any issues with your mysql adapter.

Comment: OMG that worked. Establish connection works in script/console but the database.yml seems to be either ignored or the :host parameter is ignored.

Comment: cool..just wanted to know what is the version of mysql gem you have been using? I would suggest you to use the native mysql 2.7 gem since you are running on rails 2.3.X app. Might be the mysql gem adpater itself has a problem when trying to connect to the remote host.

Comment: sweet.. I am happy hear that !! :)